# How can I confirm that the server will add a leap second on 1 Jan 2017?

Tags: linux, ntp

How can I confirm that the server will add a leap second on 1 Jan 2017? Is there is log on `ntpd`?

Comment: Are you trying to confirm whether it will in the future or confirm that it has already?

Comment: I am trying to confirm whether it will happen in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `zdump -v right/UTC`

Output example:

> right/UTC  Tue Jun 30 23:59:60 2015 UT = Tue Jun 30 23:59:60 2015 UTC isdst=0 gmtoff=0
>   right/UTC  Wed Jul  1 00:00:00 2015 UT = Wed Jul  1 00:00:00 2015 UTC isdst=0 gmtoff=0

`23:59:60` - is entry for the last leap second in current tzdata database.